# How to show a particular text when clicked on another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is when someone clicks on the read more button. The rest of the hidden text should show up. To some extent I have been able to achieve what I want with this code. But the problem is when I click on the read more button all the articles are expanded, whereas I just want to expand the particular one which is clicked.

Also I could have used different div names for each article and used the hide show property on it but there are a lot of articles so I can't make my code redundant.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".hide").hide(); 
    $(".more").click(function(){
        $(".hide").show(600);
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
//@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
//@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
nav{
 z-index: 100;
}

body {
 z-index: 99;
}

header{
 z-index: 99;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 z-index: 99;
 padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
 font-family: 'Raleway','Sans Serif';
 font-size: 40px;
}

.Template {
 z-index: 99;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-family: 'Raleway','Sans Serif';
 letter-spacing: 1px;

}
.more{
 cursor:pointer;
}
img{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.imghold{
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 20px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Template">
 <h2>Heading</h2>
 <div class="imghold"><img src="" alt="insert"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
 <br>
 <div class="more">
  Read More
 </div>
 <P class="hide">
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
</div>
<div class="Template">
 <h2>Heading</h2>
 <div class="imghold"><img src="" alt="insert"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
 <br>
 <div class="more">
  Read More
 </div>
 <P class="hide">
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Also if the text on expanding could fadeIn like a block instead of the animation now it would be better.

Comment: Use "id" instead of "class" for this type of functionality.

Comment: @PawanLakhara I dont think use of Id/class makes any difference to the functionality.If you could provide some articles regrading this it would be  better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.next()` instead of common class `hide`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".hide").hide(); 
    $(".more").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".hide").show(600);
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
//@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
//@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
nav{
 z-index: 100;
}

body {
 z-index: 99;
}

header{
 z-index: 99;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 z-index: 99;
 padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
 font-family: 'Raleway','Sans Serif';
 font-size: 40px;
}

.Template {
 z-index: 99;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-family: 'Raleway','Sans Serif';
 letter-spacing: 1px;

}
.more{
 cursor:pointer;
}
img{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.imghold{
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 20px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Template">
 <h2>Heading</h2>
 <div class="imghold"><img src="" alt="insert"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
 <br>
 <div class="more">
  Read More
 </div>
 <P class="hide">
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
</div>
<div class="Template">
 <h2>Heading</h2>
 <div class="imghold"><img src="" alt="insert"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
 <br>
 <div class="more">
  Read More
 </div>
 <P class="hide">
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector does affect all the elements of `.hide` class, you need to specify only the one that is in the same `<div>` as the clicked `.more` button. Like so:

`$(".more").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children(".hide").show(600);
        $(this).hide();
    });`

Comment: Also I would suggest that you rethink the logic of that operation. I'd do it having the whole text in one single `<p>` which has specific height given with css and overflow hidden. On click make the height auto with javascript and you have your `read more` button functioning automatically.